# BASH Script: Cancelar comando y pasar al siguiente

Tags: bash, script

Estoy trabajando en un bash script cuya función es registrar datagramas recibidos por UDP.
La idea es hacerlo utilizando `nc -ul <puerto>`

El problema es que necesito hacer esto en tres puertos diferentes, pero como éste comando se queda esperando datagramas, nunca pasa al siguiente.

Mi pregunta es:

Existe un equivalente al ctrl+c que poder introducir en un script? Como cancelo un comando y paso al siguiente desde el propio codigo?

**EDIT**

Utilizando '&' al final del código consigo que el programa pase a la linea siguiente del script, sin embargo, por razones que desconozco no puedo guardar la salida del comando ni en una variable ni en un archivo externo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Descubre cual es el pid del proceso del `nc` y le mandas un `kill -INT <pid>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes dejar colgado el proceso hasta que reciba algo, y mientas dejas que se ejecute en segundo plano; estu usando el token `&`. Por ejemplo:

```
nc -klU 2222 &
echo "PID=$!"

nc -klU 3333 &
echo "PID=$!"

nc -klU 4444 &
echo "PID=$!"
```

Además de añadir el parámetro `-k` para crear una conexión persistente.

Y ya manualmente puedes ejecutar algún comando como `kill`, `pkill`, con el número de proceso; o incluso un `pgrep -f <nombre del comando>`, en caso de que quieras cerrar algún proceso.

Comment: He probado esta solución, pero me presenta otro problema. Gracias al & puedo pasar a la siguiente linea de código y por tanto ejecutar los siguientes nc y kills. Sin embargo, necesito guardar la salida de los nc en algún sitio, pero al añadir el & por alguna razón que desconozco soy incapaz de hacerlo. He probado con `nc -ul 2222 > archivo &` y con `var=$(nc -ul 2222 &)` .

He podido comprobar que sin el & los comandos funcionan correctamente y guarda su valor sin problemas, pero claro, no pasan a la siguiente linea. Alguna idea?

Comment: @ROGERMOCHOLISEGURA Que bueno que te haya funcionado. SI te funcionó para lo que establecías en tu pregunta, puedes marcar la respuesta como la válida. Si tienes otra duda, podrías crear otro post y elaborarla ahi. De esa manera el contenido del sitio estará más desacoplado y sería más legible.

Comment: Es que no acaba de resolver mi problema, ya que de nada me sirve que pase a la siguiente linea si no puedo ver la salida del comando de ninguna forma

Comment: Tu pregunta inicial era, "Existe un equivalente al ctrl+c que poder introducir en un script? Como cancelo un comando y paso al siguiente desde el propio codigo?"
No pedías nada respecto a la salida.
Te sugiero no editar este post tuyo, sino crear otro nuevo con otra nueva duda.

Comment: Por cierto, edité mi respuesta para añadirle persistencia a la conexión.

Comment: te lo compro. Por otra parte he probado el parametro -k y me dice que el modo UDP (parametro -u) no admite la conexion persistente

Comment: Vaya. Me confundí. Utilizé el parametro `-U` en lugar de `-u` para UDP.

Answer (score 0):

*Encontrado en esta respuesta del SO en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789642/how-to-send-controlc-from-a-bash-script*

`Control + C` envía una señal `SIGINT`.

```
# Termina el programa (como Ctrl+C)
kill -INT 888
# Fuerza el kill
kill -9 888
```

Asumiendo que 888 es el id del proceso (PID).

Y para descubrir el id del proceso se puede realizar de este modo:

```
# Lanza el comando en background
nc -ul <puerto>
# Obtiene su PID
PID=$!
# Espera para testear durante 2 segundos
sleep 2
# Ejecuta el Control + C 
kill -INT $PID
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 2 opciones:

**Resultado por pantalla**

La primera es lanzar los comandos que quieras, ponerlos en segundo plano y esperar a que terminen para que muestre su salida por pantalla. Con un ejemplo simple sería así:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 5 && echo "out 1" &
sleep 8 && echo "out 2" &

wait
```

Este ejemplo espera unos segundos y luego muestra un texto. Si lo ejecutas verás que espera hasta que terminan todas las acciones que están en segundo plano (gracias a `wait`) y muestra por pantalla sus resultados

**Guardar en variable**

La segunda opción es ejecutar cada comando guardando su salida en una variable. Con los mismos comandos que antes sería:

```
#!/bin/bash

out1=`sleep 5 && echo "out 1" &`
out2=`sleep 8 && echo "out 2" &`
```

En este caso no mostrará nada por pantalla (si quieres ver el resultado por pantalla pon al final un `echo $out1` para ver la salida del primer comando) pero espera igualmente a que finalice la ejecución. Si luego quieres hacer algo con la salida de los comandos puedes ponerlo seguido.

Espero que te pueda servir

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero  al usar las comillas guarda la linea de comando en sí, no su salida. A no ser que esté pasando algo por alto. Por otra parte "wait" requiere parametros como sleep? en que se diferencian?

Comment: Si pones comilla simple `'` lo que guarda es el texto que pones, pero si le pones el acento grave `\`` te guarda la salida. Si copias directamente el código que he puesto lo verás. Por otro lado, `sleep` lo que hace es esperar el tiempo que tú le pongas, y `wait` lo que hace es esperar a que termine uno o varios procesos. Si lo dejas sin parámetros espera todos los procesos, si le pasas el ID de alguno de los procesos solo espera a ese.